# can't see a way around global var

Tags: python

I am just learning to script python working my way thru MIT comp. science open course and I have a question. I have read that setting vars to global inside of functions is the root of, well at least some evil. Although I am sure there is an obvious answer to my question, I could not see a way around NOT setting a global var in my func 'rand_guess' because I need the values from the func in the main body's while loop to perform further processing. I hope then someone might describe a more acceptable (pythonic I think is the term) way I could do so. Here is my script:

```
# Instruct the user to pick an arbitrary number from 1 to 100 and proceed to
# guess it correctly within 10 attempts. After each guess, the user must tell
# whether their number is higher than, lower than, or equal to your guess.


def rand_guess(l, h):
    # print "l: " + str(l)
    # print "h: " + str(h)
    # global rand_num
    rand_num = random.randint(l, h)
    print(str(cntr) + '_2: ' + str(rand_num))  # debug
    if rand_num != user_num:
        if cntr < attempts:
            print '\nMy guess of ' + str(rand_num) + ' is wrong.'
            # global hi_lo
            hi_lo = raw_input('So should my next guess be [H]igher or [L]ower? ')
            print(str(cntr) + '_2: ' + hi_lo)  # debug
        else:
            print '\nMy guess of ' + str(rand_num) + \
                ' is wrong, and I am out of guesses.\n'
            exit()

    else:
        print '\nWoW! I can hardly believe it! My guess is correct: ' + \
            str(user_num) + '\n'
        exit()

    return rand_num
    return hi_lo


import random

attempts = 5
rand_num = 1
hi_lo = ''
lo = 1
hi = 100

user_num = int(raw_input('\nEnter a number between 1 to 100: '))

cntr = 1
while cntr < (attempts+1):
    # first guess will be a random num between 1 to 100 so first lo_num must be
    print(str(cntr) + '_1: ' + hi_lo)  # debug
    print(str(cntr) + '_1: ' + str(rand_num))  # debug
    # 1
    if cntr == 1:
        rand_guess(lo, hi)
    else:
        # if user indicated to guess Higher with next guess
        print(str(cntr) + '_3: ' + hi_lo)  # debug
        if hi_lo == 'H':
            # then last number guessed +1 should be the lowest number guessed
            # for all future guesses
            print(str(cntr) + '_3: ' + str(rand_num))  # debug
            if rand_num > lo:
                lo = rand_num + 1
        # user indicated to guess Lower with next guess
        else:
            # then last number guessed -1 should be the highest number guessed
            # for all future guesses
            if rand_num < hi:
                hi = rand_num - 1

        # func call with new lo-hi guess brackets
        rand_guess(lo, hi)

    cntr += 1
```

In addition, I would appreciate reading any others constructive suggestions regarding obvious python formatting faux pas I might be making, as I realize format in python is of the utmost importance.

**EDIT:**
Ok so I replaced the `global` statements with `return` statements, like what I originally tried and still the values I expect to be returned seem to be causing me problems. I added in some additional `print` statements to try to help determine what value a given var is at different points in the code. Here is the output of this script, including python debug details:

```
Enter a number between 1 to 100: 50
1_1: 
1_1: 1
1_2: 61

My guess of 61 is wrong.
So should my next guess be [H]igher or [L]ower? L
1_2: L
2_1: 
2_1: 1
2_3: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex_loops2.py", line 67, in <module>
    rand_guess(lo, hi)
  File "ex_loops2.py", line 10, in rand_guess
    rand_num = random.randint(l, h)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 241, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 217, in randrange
    raise ValueError, "empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width)
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)
02:53 exercises $
```

The first empty value for `print` '2_1: ' should have been 'H' (in this instance) and the value '1' for the second `print' '2_1: 1' right before pythons throws its error I expected to be '2_1: 61' (again for this particular instance, the returned value of 'rand_num').

So again, if I simply `global` those vars the script works as expected. I am sure someone can point out my obvious oversight or omission or wrong assumption and use of python's `return` statement here, because I am stumped.

While I can see how Justin's modified example below is a much better revision of what I am trying to accomplish here, I really just to need to know what it is I am doing wrong trying to `return` these particular var values so they are available outside of the func in which they are assigned (since the script basically works otherwise). I think remaining in the context I am having problems will yield the greatest benefit regarding this basic aspect of python.

Comment: you usually return those things rather than use a global variable ... how is it not just quitting your program any time you call rand guess ... why are you calling `exit()` ?...

Comment: You get things into a function by passing them as arguments. You get stuff out by returning them as the function's return value. Python is extremely flexible about both, so globals are rarely needed.

Comment: @Joran calling `exit()` after the number is correctly guessed, and so no need for any further action. It seems like an adequate way to deal with what I need here, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: @Joran before I resorted to `global`ling the vars I did have them set to `return rand_num` and `return hi_lo` at the end of the function, which if the `exit()` func was not called I though should then have made the var values available to the part of the script which called the func in the first place. But it did not appear to do so, as I used print statements to verify the empty values of the vars after the func had cycled. So I tried `global`ling them and that worked as I expected. So not sure then what I did wrong with the `return` statements that they did not work.

Comment: @Joran I am sorry, but why do you think it should just quit when func rand_guess is called? It doesn't and I am not sure why it you might expect it to.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but it should give some pointers.

```
import sys
import random

def random_guess(low=1, high=100, attempts=10, hints=True):
    """Try to guess the random number.

    Args:
        low (int): Lowest number the value can be.
        high (int): Highest number the value can be.
        attempts (int): How many tries you get.
        hints (bool): Change range boundaries.
    """
    # Command line args come in as strings.
    low = int(low)
    high = int(high)
    attempts = int(attempts)
    hints = hints in [True, 1, "True", 'true', '1', 't', 'y', 'yes']

    mynum = None
    rand_num = random.randint(low, high)
    for _ in range(attempts): # _ means the last command ... i isn't used. Skips the pylint warning
        # Check input
        if hints and mynum is not None:
            if mynum < rand_num:
                low = mynum + 1
                print("Incorrect answer! Guess higher next time")
            elif mynum > rand_num:
                high = mynum - 1
                print("Incorrect answer! Guess lower next time")
        elif mynum is not None:
            print("Incorrect answer!", end=" ")

        # Ask the user for input (raw_input for python 2.x)
        try:
            mynum = int(input('Enter a number between '+str(low)+' to '+str(high)+': '))
            if mynum == rand_num:
                print("Congratulations, you win!")
                return # skip the print you lose and exit the function
        except ValueError:
            print("That wasn't a number.")
    # end for

    print("Sorry you lose!")
# end main


# Use name to check if it is the main. This prevents the below code from executing on import.
# So another application and import the random_guess method and use it without actually running it.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    commandline_args = sys.argv[1:] # First argument is usually the filename
    random_guess(*commandline_args) # run the main method
```

Comment: I can follow most of the changes you suggest. I see how you replaced my `while` with a `for` loop which looks little more streamlined and more importantly included it within the func thereby removing the need for global vars to be processed outside of the func, but then I just gotta ask, why put it into a func at all? I also see that you enclose `print` statements in () since they are args for the `print` func to process. Makes sense. Last part after `#main` remains Greek to me ATM, but will hopefully become clear before long. So thanks for the alternate script, helps for sure.

Comment: @scriptz I just like to put everything in functions for readability and re-use. You could break apart the function into a smaller function that just asks for user input and returns "High", "low", or "equal" then check the result. This would allow someone else to import your module and use that code. The () in the print statement is a python 3.x requirement. The if statement prevents that code from being run on import. If someone says "import my_module" it will run all of the code. Functions/classes are defined, but not called. The If checks if the module name is the main program executed.